# Рекурсивная функция с fetch выдаёт одно и то же

Tags: javascript

Что я хочу: выполнять запросы на неопределённое количество страниц, получать из них нужную инфу, пока не выполнится моё условие, тогда стоп. Но написанный мною код выдаёт мне только страницу по первой ссылке. Я не понимаю, почему так, ведь переменная ссылки - url, меняется. Выполнять код нужно на сайте https://dota2.ru/forum/

```
const Asmund = {
  dislike_helper: {
    request_page: async function(url) {
      let response = await fetch(url);
      let html = await response.text();
      let temp = document.createElement('div');
      temp.innerHTML = html;
      return temp;
    },

    init: function() {
      let nick = "Asmund.614367";
      let id = "614367";
      let url = "https://dota2.ru/forum/members/" + nick + "/likes/my-rate/";
      let now = Date.now(); now = now / 1000;
      let time = now;

      let i = 1;
      let fetchNow = (url, i) => {
        this.request_page(url)
          .then(result => {
            let temp = result; //получаю каждый раз страницу по первой ссылке
            time = temp.querySelector('.forum-profile__content-block-active-info time').getAttribute('data-time');
            time = parseInt(time, 10);
            console.log(time); //должно выводиться каждый раз разное число, но выводится одно и то же - с первой страницы

            if (i == 5) {
              console.log("Done");
            } else {
              i++;
              url = "https://dota2.ru/forum/members/" + nick + "/likes/my-rate/page-" + i;
              fetchNow(url, i);
            }
          })
      }
      fetchNow(url, i);
    }

  },

  init: function() {
    this.dislike_helper.init();
  }
}
Asmund.init();
```

Comment: добавляй больше логов, убедись, что у тебя меняются `i` и `url`, возможно тебе просто кажется что страница одна и та же, а на самом деле - одинаковая информация на разных страницах

Comment: Раз уж ты используешь `await` уже. Вместо странной рекурсии - используй обычный цикл

Comment: У меня куча логов в основном коде, я перепроверил всё уже очень много раз. Код здесь просто почищен от всего лишнего, что может отвлекать внимание

Comment: А цикл я не смог реализовать из-за того, что его невозможно (или я не нашёл способ) остановить, если внутри него находится функция

Comment: так ты и тут не можешь остановить выполнение, пока функция выполняется :-) Просто с циклом это было бы в 2 строки и все понятно, а с рекурсией ты сам запутался